# Loading NOAA Nautical Charts .bsb format into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

Is it possible to load a nautical chart from [NOAA](http://www.charts.noaa.gov/RNCs/RNCsIndv.shtml) into QGIS that has the .bsb format? 
Didn't have much luck with mrSID format.

using QGIS(dev) on ubuntu 13.04

Comment: You could convert this with GDAL (http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#BSB) to something else (e.g. TIFF), but I'm not sure if there is a way to do this "natively" with QGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa on Windows and Ubuntu 12.04, I had no problem opening the first `.kap` file from Chart 50 as raster source. And it fits good to a Openstreetmap background.

I assume that the `.bsb` file only contains some metadata of the chart.

BSB is listed under `Settings -> Options`, GDAL tab. Is this missing on Ubuntu dev version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, QGIS (version PI) reads the BSB format directly:

[image: Settings>Options]

On the BSB file format: [link](https://legacy.iho.int/mtg_docs/com_wg/HSSC/HSSC3/S-64_Edition_2.0.0/RNC_Test_Data_Sets/BSB_TDS/BSB_Test_Dataset_Instructions_for_RNC.pdf)